# Verify text in Robotframework

Tags: automation, robotframework, selenium2library

I am want to verify text of an element. How to verify text is one of many strings: Such as: "Login fail" , "Error login", "Attempt fail"... ?

```
*** Keywords ***

Assert Warning Message

    Element Should Contain    id=session_key-login-error  "Login fail"
```

Comment: Have you read through available documentation to see how to get element text, and how to verify that a  list contains a value? Which part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: May be this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242291/robotframework-how-to-check-text-on-page

Answer (score 1):

So I would create a list with the element that are accepted and then make a command list should contain;

Example:

```
@{expected_results}    Create List    your_1_acceptance_criteria_element    your_2_acceptance_criteria_element    your_3_acceptance_criteria_element
${world}=    set variable   your_element 
List Should Contain Value    @{expected_results}    ${world}
```

Name:List Should Contain Value
Source:Collections 
Arguments:[ list_ | value | msg=None ]

Fails if the value is not found from list. 
If the keyword fails, the default error messages is  does not contain value ''. A custom message can be given using the msg argument.

Comment: This won't work. Well, technically it will run, but it almost certainly won't do what the OP wants. Your code simply searches for the id itself, not the text of an element identified by that id. If your intent was to show how to search for a string in a list of strings, I recommend changing  your example to use something like `${word}` instead of `${id}`, and setting the value to a string rather than something of the form "x=y".

Comment: Hi Bryan I modify the example but as you say this is an example then he can use my example as base implement what he need... why score -1? yes I was doing it specifically for an ID element but it's up to him put the correct value, we are here to help not to do the job for other people

Comment: your example is still incorrect. Your last line `list should contain value` doesn't have the proper number of arguments.

Comment: So my understanding of the ticket is that he has a list of accepted values, then he retrieve an element with a specific ID and he want accept the test case if the value retrieved is present in the list... if I'm wrong please let me know so I can give a better answer

Comment: So if h select the correct element and introduce the value in ${word} it should work!