# Robot Framework : Random Selection of Drop downs

Tags: random, robotframework, testcase

I need some help, I want to create a test that will randomly get the value during test case since in my case I declared it in my code, how can I make this randomly?

Heres my code

**html**

```
<select name="gender">
    <option>Please Select</option>
    <option value='Male'>Male</option>
    <option value='Female'>Female</option>
</select>
```

**robot**

```
*** Test Cases ***
Select From List By Value    xpath://select[@name='gender']    Male
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ['Random Element' from the Faker Library](https://guykisel.github.io/robotframework-faker/#Random%20Element). `Random Element` returns a random item from the list of items provided.

```
*** Settings *** 
Library    FakerLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Randomise gender selection
    ${gender}    Select random gender    
    Select from list by value   xpath://select[@name='gender']    ${gender}   

*** Keywords ***
Select random gender
    ${randomValue}    Random Element    ['Male', 'Female']

    [Return]    ${randomValue}
```

This will randomise gender selection in the test case. In case you want to add more items to your list, you can add it in the list argument following the `Random Element` keyword.

> Note: Make sure to install and import the [FakerLibrary](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-faker/)

Comment: hi sir. do you have any sample test or docu using assertion in robot framework? thank you.

Comment: @rkevx21 , I'm not sure about what exactly you're asking. I'd suggest you check SO with your exact requirement. If you do not find any relevant question/answer you can add it as a new question. A quick search led to me this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469178/verify-text-in-robotframework). Is this something similar to what you're looking for?